# GAE - Interpreting datastore indexes limits

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing, limit, google-cloud-datastore

Google documentation says:

> The Datastore imposes limits on the number and overall size of index entries that can be associated with a single entity. These limits are large, and most applications are not affected. However, there are circumstances in which you might encounter the limits.

I have some difficulties to interpret these words (probably beacuse of my ignorance about the argument).  By default The datastore creates a single index for any (not defined as unindexed) entity property. Therefore if I define entity PIZZA as:

```
PIZZA{
   "name" : "somename";
   "price" : <someprice>;
   "property3" : "...";
   ...
   "propertyN" : "...";
}
```

Then when I "put" this entity in the datastore, it creates N+2 indexes (one for each property defined).

Now I decide to create another PIZZA entity with M properties and R of these M properties are different from the N+2 defined in the first entity.
Thus the database will insert the new entity in the index tables of the M-R properties that are in common with the first PIZZA and creates additional R indexes.

Now the question: the indexes limits are on the number of indexed properties of any enetity (in this case on N+2) or on the total number of indexes that can contain PIZZA entities? (in this case N+R) ?  or again on the total number of indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This size limit refers to the number of index fields (rows times properties) to which the entity contributes property values, not a number of indexes.  When referring just to the built-in (automatic) indexes, it's simply a count of the indexable properties of an entity, since each property value appears just once in each built-in index.  The count increases as that property contributes to custom indexes for complex queries.

This limit is more noticeable when you have indexed multi-valued properties.  Such a property contributes one row per value to the built-in index.  It also increases the number of times each property appears in a custom index, because all combinations of all indexed values must be represented in the custom index, so many get repeated.  If I have a custom index of Pizza entities with a `crust_type` single-value property and a `toppings` multi-valued property, with an entity that has three `toppings` values, the `crust_type` property contributes three times to that index, one for each `toppings` value.

There's a related limit to the total value size equal to the size of each value multiplied by the number of index rows in which the value appears.  Both limits are for the properties of a single entity.

Comment: Thus I can define safely as much properties as I want in any entity right? (unless I overcome the 1Mb entity size limit)

Comment: I mean in two entites of the same kind I can define for each one an arbitrary se of different properties? (different among tboth properties defined in each one and among the overall set of properties)

Comment: Yes.  The indexed property limit has no bearing on two entities of the same kind with disjunct property sets.  The built-in indexes are per kind+property (one for `Pizza: crust_type`, one for `Pizza: toppings`), they're not traditional tables like you'd find in a relational database.  Only custom indexes have multiple properties as columns.

Comment: Ok thank you. Last question: if I have some objects of kind W and I want to classify them using weighted hashtags (the weight measures the strength on the link between an object and a tag), then I can simply create for any entity of W a number of poperties equal to the number of tags associated with it having name = to the tag name and value = weight and I'm sure that no matter the total number of different tags, I just need to limit to 20000 the numbero of tags associated to a single entity of kind W (that is limit the number of properties of any entity of W) right?

Comment: and what about the 200 limit "Number of Indexes" ?

Comment: Re: implementing weighted tags as named properties, that's doable. Whether that's the best solution depends on how you are using the properties, especially with queries. Re: the index count limit, you're right, the Quota Details page says this. I'm pretty sure it refers specifically to custom indexes, not the built-in property indexes. I've done apps with more than 200 kind-property pairs. :)

Comment: Yes it is quite the worst solution because any weight adjustment will imply rewrite evrything. however it is the best on a entity lookup point of view since I can simply filter on the tag property to match all the entities tagged. I think I will go on redundancy, tht's both a "property-tagging" and a Tag-Entity realtionship Entity which stores weights. Ok Thank you for your time!